# imshow plot with no data values excluded from interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to let imshow interpolate between two colours while there is one or more no data value(s) in between.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red    = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
blue   = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
nodata = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] # Transparent black
grid   = [[red, nodata, blue]]

plt.imshow(grid, interpolation = "bilinear")
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: current_result_red_white_blue]

I have also tried with `nodata = [None]` and `nodata = numpy.nan` but they don't work either.

I could add the colour in between myself or use a function to calculate it, but that is not an option for me in this case. I specifically want to let the imshow interpolation work out this colour and skip the no data values.

How it should look like:

[image: desired_result_red_purple_blue]

Comment: imshow cannot only show equidistant pixels, try a [colormesh](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) instead.

Comment: The result looks expected. What exactly do you want to achieve instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want it to look like the second image in my post, under "How it should look like:"

Comment: Uhh, I doubt that's possible. You will either need to give those pixels the color you want them to have, or use a colormap instead of actual RGB values (and then interpolate the nan values).

Comment: @Trilarion Can you elaborate on how I would use a colormesh for this?